# Redis benchmarking for hget and hset commands

Tags: caching, redis

I could not find an example for bench marking  of HGET , HSET (hash table commands) with redis. Any example or resource will be useful regarding this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just realized `redis-benchmark` command does not benchmark `hSet` and `hGet` commands. (I'm using v2.8.5)

What you could do is write a small program to benchmark the performance:

```php
<?php

$redis = new Redis();
$redis->pconnect("127.0.0.1");

$count = 10000;

$start_t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $redis->hSet("h{$i}", 'f', $i);
}
$end_t = microtime(true);

echo "Time taken for hSet = " . round(1000 * ($end_t - $start_t)) . "ms (for " . number_format($count) . " keys)\n";

$start_t = microtime(true);
$pipeline1 = $redis->pipeline();
for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $pipeline1->hSet("h{$i}", 'f', $i);
}
$result2 = $pipeline1->exec();
$end_t = microtime(true);

echo "Time taken for hSet (bulk) = " . round(1000 * ($end_t - $start_t)) . "ms (for " . number_format($count) . " keys)\n";

$start_t = microtime(true);
for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $redis->hGet("h{$i}", 'f');
}
$end_t = microtime(true);

echo "Time taken for hGet = " . round(1000 * ($end_t - $start_t)) . "ms (for " . number_format($count) . " keys)\n";

$start_t = microtime(true);
$pipeline2 = $redis->pipeline();
for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $pipeline2->hGet("h{$i}", 'f');
}
$result2 = $pipeline2->exec();
$end_t = microtime(true);

echo "Time taken for hGet (bulk) = " . round(1000 * ($end_t - $start_t)) . "ms (for " . number_format($count) . " keys)\n";


$start_t = microtime(true);
$pipeline3 = $redis->pipeline();
for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
    $pipeline3->hDel("h{$i}", 'f');
}
$result3 = $pipeline3->exec();
$end_t = microtime(true);

echo "Time taken for hDel (bulk) = " . round(1000 * ($end_t - $start_t)) . "ms (for " . number_format($count) . " keys)\n";
```

On my test server, results are as follows:

`$ php redis/benchmark_redis.php
Time taken for hSet = 557ms (for 10,000 keys)
Time taken for hSet (bulk) = 51ms (for 10,000 keys)
Time taken for hGet = 483ms (for 10,000 keys)
Time taken for hGet (bulk) = 43ms (for 10,000 keys)
Time taken for hDel (bulk) = 49ms (for 10,000 keys)`

Answer (score 2):

i'm using 3.0.2, the following command can benchmark hset `redisredis-benchmark -h 192.168.22.58 -p 6379 -d 100 -c 10 -n 1000000 hset myhash rand_int rand_string`

Comment: The `-d` switch has no effect when specifying the command - it is only used by the tests included in `redis-benchmark`