# Redis benchmarking for HMSET, HGETALL with a data size

Tags: redis

Can someone let me know how can I use `redis-benchmark` to do a benchmarking for `HMSET`, `HGETALL` with a fixed data size (`-d` option in `redis-benchmark`). I am using `redis 3.2.5`.

I have gone through this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33293802/785523) and tried the below command:-

```
root@cache-server1:~# redis-benchmark -h a.b.c.d -p XXXX hmset hgetall myhash rand_int rand_string -d 2048
====== hmset hgetall myhash rand_int rand_string -d 2048 ======
  10000 requests completed in 0.11 seconds
  50 parallel clients
  3 bytes payload
  keep alive: 1

99.64% <= 1 milliseconds
100.00% <= 1 milliseconds
89285.71 requests per second
```

But looking at the output it seems it is using only 3 bytes payload.

If it is not possible via `redis-benchmark` can someone suggest some other alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The payload is only 3 bytes (the default) because the `-d` is taken as part of the command. The command must be the last argument, and all switches must precede it.

Besides that, you can't use `redis-benchmark` to run two custom commands. Also, the `-d` option is only applicable to predefined tests (the ones that run by default or with the `-t` option) and has no meaning if the user specifies the command used in the benchmark.

If you have a specific benchmarking flow that you want to test, the best thing you can do is mock it with any client that you're comfortable with.

Comment: If I execute the command like below `redis-benchmark -h 172.16.84.114 -p 7001 -d 2048 hmset hgetall myhash rand_int rand_string` then in the output it is showing `2048 bytes payload`. So if `-d`  does not work with custom command then don't you think the above message in the output is confusing? The full output is `====== hmset hgetall myhash rand_int rand_string ====== 10000 requests completed in 0.09 seconds 50 parallel clients 2048 bytes payload keep alive: 1 99.84% <= 1 milliseconds 100.00% <= 1 milliseconds 111111.11 requests per second`

Comment: Yes, I agree that this is somewhat confusing. I've put a PR to correct that: https://github.com/antirez/redis/pull/3674